# Need to equally add value based

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have to following array:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Useing the following iteration, I can calculate the `next` and `prev`:

```
for(i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    collections[i].next = (i+1) % collections.length;
  collections[i].prev = i > 0 ? i-1 : collections.length-1;
}
```

Following is the result:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Based on the new collections, I need to calculate each value if the pointer is `increased` or `decreased`

Example: The value for 3rd item has been increased to 25

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:25, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true},
  {value:20, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Expected Result:

```
0: {value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 19, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 25, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
```

Example 2: if the value is decreased to 2 for the same pointer.

```
var collections=[
    {value:19, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:19, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:23, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true},
  {value:18, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:19, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Following result is expected which with follow the `prev`:

```
0: {value: 20, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 20, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 23, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
```

So far I have the following code:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
var maxValue = 100;
var totalValue = 0;
var toBeDistributedNext = 0;
var toBeDistributedPrev = 0;

for(i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    collections[i].next = (i+1) % collections.length;
  collections[i].prev = i > 0 ? i-1 : collections.length-1;
}

collections[2].value = 25;
collections[2].pointer = true;

collections.forEach(function (collection) {
  totalValue += parseInt(collection.value);
});

if (totalValue > maxValue) {
    toBeDistributedNext = totalValue - maxValue;
} else {
    toBeDistributedPrev = maxValue - totalValue;
}
var currentPointer = collections.find(item => item.pointer === true);
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
  var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
  if (!collections[i%collections.length].pointer) {
    collections[i%collections.length].value--;
    collections[i%collections.length].lastUpdated = true;
    console.log(collections[i%collections.length])
    //currentPointer = collections[i%collections.length].next;
  }
}
```

The above code gives the following result: which is WRONG

```
0: {value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
1: {value: 19, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
2: {value: 25, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, …}
3: {value: 19, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
```

The last is not calculating, any one please help. **The total has to be 100**.

I have the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir_alam_shawn/zm21pLen/144/

Comment: why do you have `18` at index `3`? why not at another place and later why not take this value for increase first?

Comment: @NinaScholz It has to follow the sequence `next` and `prev`, since index 2 is already a pointer it will go to the `next`

Comment: I don't understand why you have prev/next when you actually have array indexing. What is wrong with direct addressing?

Comment: @trincot Please if you can show me an example

Comment: You have already accepted an answer. But surely you can access a "next" element by incrementing the "current" index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a function for updating the values and check the delta for distribution.

```js
function update(array, index, value) {
    function go(index, direction) {
        do {
            if (!array[index].isLocked) { // check for locked items
                array[index].value += increment;
                if (!(delta -= increment)) return;
            }
            index = array[index][direction];
        } while (!array[index].pointer)
    }
    
    let delta = array[index].value - value,
        increment = Math.sign(delta);

    array[index].value = value;
    array[index].pointer = true;

    while (delta) {
        go(array[index].prev, 'prev');
        if (!delta) break;
        go(array[index].next, 'next');
    }

    array[index].pointer = false;
}

var collections = [
        { value: 20, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: false, isLocked: false, pointer: false },
        { value: 20, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: false, isLocked: false, pointer: false },
        { value: 20, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLocked: false, pointer: false },
        { value: 20, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: false, isLocked: false, pointer: false },
        { value: 20, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: false, isLocked: false, pointer: false }
    ];

update(collections, 2, 25);
console.log(...collections.map(({ value }) => value));
update(collections, 2, 23);
console.log(...collections.map(({ value }) => value));
```

Comment: This only work if the number is evenly distributed, if fails with un-even number

Comment: If you can help me to fix this would be grateful

Comment: do you have an example of it?

Comment: how can I lock one and distribute rest to others that are not locked? if its locked, available amount in (100 - locked) and left over is distributed among others that are not locked? `isLocked`

Comment: just check the property and `continue` the loop.

Comment: its not working, I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir_alam_shawn/sncxLz8d/19/

Comment: I new to javaScript and if could show me in Jsfiddle please?

Comment: please try the above edit with `if (!array[index].isLocked) {`.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, but there's a couple of strange things in your code.

First of all, you carefully assign the current pointer with:

```
var currentPointer = collections.find(item => item.pointer === true);
```

And within your loop you assign the next pointer

```
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
    var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
```

But then in the next line you ignore all that good work:

```
if (!collections[i%collections.length].pointer)
```

`collections[i%collections.length]` doesn't point at your current pointer, see that at the beginning of your loop i is equal to 0. Instead of accessing the pointer with `i` you should use the `nextIndex` value you had already figured out.

What's more, you did yourself no favours by using an example which increases the value of 5 when your sample collections array has five items in it. Anyway, looking at your loop, see the problem:

```
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
  var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
  if (!collections[i%collections.length].pointer) {
    collections[i%collections.length].value--;
    collections[i%collections.length].lastUpdated = true;
    console.log(collections[i%collections.length])
    //currentPointer = collections[i%collections.length].next;
  }
}
```

What about when `pointer` is set to true? Well no value is changed, but i is incremented regardless, hence only 4 changes are actually made. So to fix your code, you want to use the actual indices you've already calculated, and do something when the current collection item has pointer set to true (for example, increment `toBeDistributedNext`). You also want to update the value of currenntPointer so that the next index is calculated correctly. So the loop looks like this:

```
var currentPointer = collections.find(item => item.pointer === true);
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
  var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
  if (!collections[nextIndex].pointer) {
    collections[nextIndex].value--;
    collections[nextIndex].lastUpdated = true;
  } else {
    toBeDistributedNext++;
  }

  currentPointer = collections[nextIndex];
}
```

Here's a snippet with the code working:

```js
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
var maxValue = 100;
var totalValue = 0;
var toBeDistributedNext = 0;
var toBeDistributedPrev = 0;

for(i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    collections[i].next = (i+1) % collections.length;
  collections[i].prev = i > 0 ? i-1 : collections.length-1;
}

collections[2].value = 25;
collections[2].pointer = true;

collections.forEach(function (collection) {
  totalValue += parseInt(collection.value);
});

if (totalValue > maxValue) {
    toBeDistributedNext = totalValue - maxValue;
} else {
    toBeDistributedPrev = maxValue - totalValue;
}
console.log('BEFORE', collections);
var currentPointer = collections.find(item => item.pointer === true);
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
  var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
  if (!collections[nextIndex].pointer) {
    collections[nextIndex].value--;
    collections[nextIndex].lastUpdated = true;
  } else {
    toBeDistributedNext++;
  }
  
  currentPointer = collections[nextIndex];
}

console.log("AFTER", collections)

    /*if (collections[i%collections.length].pointer && !collections[i%collections.length].lastUpdated) {
    collections[collections[i%collections.length].next%collections.length].value++;
    collections[collections[i%collections.length].next%collections.length].lastUpdated = true;
  } else {
    //????Need help, So it moves to next item and add one as you see the expected result
  }*/
/**Expected Result: with NEXT
0: {value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 19, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 25, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
*/

/**Expected Result: with PREV
0: {value: 20, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 20, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 23, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
*/

//So if its LOCKED, it will (100 - totalLocaked) and what ever is left will be distributed similary with next and prev.
```